# How to retrieve specific events from a calendar in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I made an android application that stores events in the calendar of a user's smartphone. For example, through my app, the user creates a specific event like a conference meeting and then clicks on the button "Add to Calendar". My app then sends the user to the Calendar application to perform the desired operation (adding the event to the calendar). After they're done, they're returned to my app.

Now, I want to retrieve the specific event from the calendar created through my app. 
I was thinking about getting the EVENT_ID of each event as the user adds it to the calendar and saving it in a file. I then retrieve the events from the calendar using the ids previously saved in the file. I don't know if this is good practice.
There is also the possibility that the user deletes an event through his calendar application.

So, how can I retrieve the specific events created by my application from a calendar?

Thanks.